# Open source tool for flash performance testing

Tags: flash, load-testing, performance-testing

Is there any open source tool for flash performance testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't 'load test' Flash, you profile it. So danii's Answer is relevant in the context of your original question. Your later comment, however, suggests that you actually want to load test an application that happens to use Flash on the client. Very different situation and the answer there is simply to not load test Flash itself but to isolate your efforts to the HTTP traffic. A good open source tool that you can use to achieve this is [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Check the [AS3 SWF Profiler](http://lostinactionscript.com/2008/10/06/as3-swf-profiler/) by the great **Shane McCartney**. It's quite handy as it tracks the FPS and memory usage (current and historic) and requires almost no set up. Simple and efficient!

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help me out. We have application based on flash, Ajax, Soap, xml, javascript etc. I want open source load test tool to check the application.